# assign looping result to a variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

please help me, I'm stuck to assign lopping output to a variable

here's my code

```
a = [0.5, 0.0, 1.2, 2.4, 0.1, 3.5]
for obs in a:
    if obs > 0:
       print('2')
    elif obs < 0.1:
       print('1')
```

the output is

```
2
1
2
2
2
2
```

I want to save that output in to a variable

Comment: Are you aware that your second condition is equivalent to `obs <= 0`? What's the point of using `0.1`? What if you had `0.05` in the list?

Comment: the resolution is 0.1

Comment: That won't change how python behaves from a practical point of view. If you have 0.00001, python will assign 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable out of the loop and save the value there or for a more "pythonic way" you can use list comprenhension

```
b = [1 if i <0.1 else 2 for i in a]
```

b is:

```
[2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, store the result in the list 'b', as in below example

```
a = [0.5, 0.0, 1.2, 2.4, 0.1, 3.5]
b=[]
for obs in a:
    if obs > 0:
        b.append(2)
    elif obs < 0.1:
        b.append(1)

print(b)
```

```
[2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: good answer, but with this you'd get a list of caracters. `b.append(2)` (with no single quotes) for a numeric output :)

Comment: @Andrew not sure why I added quotes earlier. I updated the response

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly the easiest way would be to use another list and append the output to that list.

Something like this:

```
a = [0.5, 0.0, 1.2, 2.4, 0.1, 3.5]

#Output list that will be written to
output = []

for obs in a:
  if obs > 0:
    #Adds '2' to the end of the output list
    output.append('2')
  elif obs < 0.1:
    #Adds '1' to the end of the output list
    output.append('1')

#Loop to print the contents of output
for n in output:
  print(n)
```

Output would be:

```
2
1
2
2
2
2
```